# checking if user is already logged in through cfloginuser

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

I'm using cfloginuser as a security mechanism in my application to secure web service calls that are being made.

One thing I would like to do is stop a second user from logging into the same account when they are already logged into another computer. Essentially what's happening, is that since both share the same username, the first one to login just gets kicked out as a logged in a user once the second login occurs.

Is there anyway I can check if a particular username is already logged in, therefore not even allowing the second login to even authenticate? (You can only be logged into one computer at a time)

Comment: I think it's better to kick out / take over the earlier session.  

If it's restricted to earliest session and that first session becomes inaccessible for whatever reason, the person then needs to wait for it to timeout before they can login again, which is annoying.

Comment: Good point Peter. This is actually a Flex app, so there is the possibility that the original user wouldn't know they've been logged off until they try to do something that communicated back to the user. I'll just have to check, and log them off accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of would be to store the user name in the application scope, and then remove it when they sign out. (and add it OnSessionEnd in your application.cfc in case they don't click the sign out link)

Then, when a user signs in, check the list of signed in users in your application scope, and don't allow them to do it a second time if the name is there.

Do keep in mind what Peter said, though.  I think it is a good point.

Comment: I'm going to go with Peter's suggestions, but I think this is the only way that you could do what I was originally thinking. It's unfortunate there's nothing built into coldfusion for this...